# Path of a ray of light in curved Universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, geodesics

Would a ray of light, travelling in a straight line, eventually come back to its original position?

If universe is curved, closed and finite (Is it? - I've read contradicting claims)

Comment: Present observations suggest that the universe is flat and therefore infinite, though it could be closed/open with a very large radius of curvature.

Answer (score 4):

To understand the trajectory of light, one takes the FLRW metric and solve for a null-geodesic in the case of a closed universe ($k=1$). So the FLRW-metric in this setting is (with $c=1$):

$$ ds^2 = -dt^2 + a(t)^2\frac{dr^2}{1-r^2} + a(t)^2 r^2 d\Omega^2$$

with $d\Omega$ being the usual solid angle for the 2-Sphere and $a(t)$ the scale factor which is determined by the matter content and the Friedmann equations. For light, that is  a null-geodesic, one can obtain the following equation:

$$\frac{dt}{a(t)} = \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$

Therefore performing an integration on both sides and solving the right hand side you get:

$$r = \sin\left(\int_{t_0}^t \frac{dt'}{a(t')}\right)$$

Now independent of the matter content we can say that the scale factor is always greater than zero. (I assumed the ray started at $r_0=0$.) You can see now that unless the integral is less than $\pi$ for all times, the light ray will be able to come back to the starting point. So if the matter content is such that allows for a static universe $a(t)=cte$ you will always be able to come back for example. If $\dot{a}<0$ one will be able to find a future time at which the ray will be back. If $\dot{a} > 0$ it will depend on it's exact behaviour and it can not be concluded a priori.

Comment: And is the universe closed? Thanks for this by the way.

Comment: Yes that is meant by $k=1$.

Comment: I thought it was an assumption?

Comment: It is an assumption at the beginning it was used. It doesn't need to be the case.